# Button dimension with an image

Tags: android, button, drawable

Can you help me to solve my little problem???
I have a table made of buttons. In my xml file the buttons has this code

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/b_0xa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_0xa" />
```

In my main.class I have this line:

```
b_0xb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
```

because I want to change the button's background after I clicked it.
It works fine but when I run my application this is the result.

[image]

How can I fix it??
I need a Button with the width==height.

thanks a lot

Comment: Ca you post the whole layout XML file? Do you use a GridView ? or how do you group all the buttons together?

Answer (score 0):

I group all the Buttons in a Table Layout this is the code

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_0xa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_0xa" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_0xb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_0xb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_0xc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_0xc" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_0xd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_0xd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_0xe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_0xe" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_0xf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_4xb" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_1xa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_1xa" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_1xb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_1xb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_1xc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_1xc" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_1xd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_1xd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_1xe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_1xe" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_1xf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/b_4xb" />
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways, i am not sure but want to let u try below things.

1) Remove  `android:layout_weight="1"`.

2) set static height and  weight in xml like layout_width ="50dip" layout_Height ="50dip"

3) set Height in Activity/onCreate by checking width parameter. like view.getHeight(); ...